# Разделение предложения по запятой с дополнительным условием с помощью регулярных выражений на python

Tags: python, регулярные-выражения, re

Всем привет!

Пытаюсь написать регулярку, которая разделяла бы предложение по запятой, если после неё есть минимум три слова.

Вот то, что у меня получается:

```
text = я бы хотел, нет, я бы очень хотел разделять по запятой.
re.split(r',(?=( [А-ЯЁа-яёA-Za-z]+){3,})', string=text)
```

На выходе это даёт список с лишним словом:
['я бы хотел, нет', ' запятой', ' я бы очень хотел разделять по запятой']

Как мне получить ['я бы хотел, нет', ' я бы очень хотел разделять по запятой']?

Всем заранее спасибо!

Comment: text.split(',')

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Используйте

```
,(?=\s*\w+(?:\s+\w+){2})
```

См. [пример работы выражения](https://regex101.com/r/o5DSiB/1).

**Подробности**

- `,` - запятая
- `(?=\s*\w+(?:\s+\w+){2})` - блок предварительного просмотра вперёд, требующий наличия (сразу после текущей позиции):

  - `\s*` - один и более пробельных символов
  - `\w+` - один и более букво-цифровых символов и символов нижнего подчёркивания
  - `(?:\s+\w+){2}` - два повтора одного и более пробельных символов + одного и более букво-цифровых символов и символов нижнего подчёркивания.

Comment: Спасибо за помощь!